# Spring JPA entity findBy<Parameter> method giving values in 1st attempt and null in 2nd call?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository

I have a Spring JPA method to get entity -> findBy<SomeCode>().
The spring boot application comes up and on making a 1st rest call the entity comes up with all values filled.
When tried  with 2nd attempt the two entity members coming 'null' which should not be - as other values are there. And there is data in db.

This goes on alternate basis i.e. if I run again 3rd it comes up filled up while on 4th attempt two entity members again come null.

The code log line is as below -

```
 Site site = siteRepo.findByCode(inputSiteCode);
    if (site != null) {
        log.info("UPDATION CASE");
        log.info("site code -> "+ site.getCode()+" lat  -> "+ site.getLat() +" lng  -> "+ site.getLng() );
```

My entity piece which is coming null on alternate runs

```
@Column(precision = 9, scale = 6)
private BigDecimal lat;
@Column(precision = 9, scale = 6)
private BigDecimal lng;
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface SiteRepository extends JpaRepository<Site, Integer> {

public List<Site> findAll();

public Site findAllById(int id);

public Site findByCode(Integer code);

}
```

The two logs in 2 calls are as follows:

1. Success case logs

```
Hibernate: select site0_.id as id1_6_, site0_.address as address2_6_, site0_.city as city3_6_, site0_.code as code4_6_, site0_.details as details5_6_, site0_.lat as lat6_6_, site0_.lng as lng7_6_, site0_.name as name8_6_, site0_.scheduler_id as schedule9_6_, site0_.state as state10_6_, site0_.zip as zip11_6_ from mow_site site0_ where site0_.code=?

2022-05-22 21:55:27.931  INFO 44064 --- [cTaskExecutor-5] c.m.d.b.SiteDataProcessor                : UPDATION CASE
2022-05-22 21:55:27.931  INFO 44064 --- [cTaskExecutor-5] c.m.d.b.SiteDataProcessor                : site code -> 83 lat  -> 32.638450 lng  -> -97.347690
address -> 7501 JBrown Rd
```

2. Failure (Empty lat/lng) Case

```
Hibernate: select site0_.id as id1_6_, site0_.address as address2_6_, site0_.city as city3_6_, site0_.code as code4_6_, site0_.details as details5_6_, site0_.lat as lat6_6_, site0_.lng as lng7_6_, site0_.name as name8_6_, site0_.scheduler_id as schedule9_6_, site0_.state as state10_6_, site0_.zip as zip11_6_ from mow_site site0_ where site0_.code=?

2022-05-22 21:56:57.356  INFO 44064 --- [cTaskExecutor-6] c.m.d.b.SiteDataProcessor                : UPDATION CASE
2022-05-22 21:56:57.364  INFO 44064 --- [cTaskExecutor-6] c.m.d.b.SiteDataProcessor                : site code -> 83 lat  -> null lng  -> null
address -> 7501 JBrown Rd
```

I would appreciate the help.
Thanks

Comment: I agree that's not enough information for an answer. For starters, you can add `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` in your `application.properties` file to see what query is being made under the hoods in the first and second attempts.

Comment: Sure, I will make that true and see the queries . and try to post my findings. Just to check , have you seen the attached logs ?

Comment: @TomazFernandes 
I checked with show-sql and the queries formed are same .

Comment: @cliff2310 Can you tell me what more info I should add to tell the issue ?
Afaik this is what I am facing for each alternate queryies lat , lng get fillled from repository. 

I am adding the repo to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in spring jpa find method what I just found out.

It was something written after each successful call which is making the columns null and then when I was trying they came null and refilled again.

I apologise for wasting your time.
I will be deleting the  post after sometime as this is not at all the issue.

Thanks